# CSS Search Box Alignment Issue in iPad/iPhone Only

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, height, alignment

I am encountering issues with aligning a CSS Search Input Box like the Google style one found on this [tutorial page](http://www.queness.com/post/8434/re-create-googles-search-input-field-and-submit-button).

I have edited the code to suit my design but for some reason I am unable to get this to align properly within the iPhone/iPad with the right element not aligning with the left element at the bottom.

[The alignment issue can be seen here](http://img102.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=791279549_searchbox_122_156lo.jpg)

The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="search">
    <form name="" action="" type="">
    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" />
    <div id="delete"><span id="x">x</span></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#search {float:left; margin:11px 0 0 156px;}
#field {float:left;width:200px; height:22px; line-height:22px; text-indent:0px; font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#999; background: #fff; background:url('search-icon.png') no-repeat left center; padding-left:25px; border:solid 1px #d9d9d9; border-right:none; -webkit-appearance:none; -webkit-border-radius:0px;}
#field:focus {outline:none;}
#delete {float:left; width:16px; height:24px; line-height:22px; padding:0 0 0 6px; font-family:"Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode",sans-serif; font-size:14px; background:#FFFFFF; border:solid 1px #D9D9D9; border-left:none; -webkit-appearance:none; -webkit-border-radius:0px;}
#delete #x {color:#999999; cursor:pointer; display:none; }
#delete #x:hover {color:#666666;}
```

I noticed that changing the height:24px below:

```
#delete {float:left; width:16px; height:24px; line-height:22px; padding:0 0 0 6px; font-family:"Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode",sans-serif; font-size:14px; background:#FFFFFF; border:solid 1px #D9D9D9; border-left:none; -webkit-appearance:none; -webkit-border-radius:0px;}
```

To height:27px; aligns correctly in Safari on the iPad/iPhone but then doesn't display correctly on IE/FF/Chrome.

Any help would be very much appreciated with this. Thanks

Comment: Here is the link to a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YwZ8w/

Answer (score 1):

I tested locally it works, if you add the following on top of your page then the problem should be fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this caused the left side to be bigger than the right in the browsers.

Comment: Can you provide a link; so I can look at it.

Comment: I have updated the answer, as I found the code was causing problem aligning the height. But I tested on jsfiddle it did not work, which worked locally.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I have changed the DOCTYPE at [link](http://www.lyyk.com/search.html) and still encounter the problem on the iPad/iPhone.

Comment: can you send your actual link? not on jsfiddle

Comment: The actual link can be seen at [here](http://www.lyyk.com/search.html) which has height at 24px and also [here](http://www.lyyk.com/search1.html) which has height set at 22px

Comment: I just checked first link on http://www.ipadpeek.com and seems working but am not sure this site works exactly like ipad. you might wanna clear cache and try again.

Comment: I have just deleted the cache on my iPad 2 and still facing problems. Any further suggestions would be much appreciated. Ty

Comment: if still not working then target different css for ipad
something like this <style type="text/css" media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)">

Answer (score 1):

Set `#delete {height:22px;}`

The height on your `#field` is set to 22px so it must be the same on `#delete`.

As a side note, I'm sure you do already, but if not, Firebug or Chrome tools can be very helpful in debugging CSS, HTML, Javascript, and much more.

THE FIX

OK. I troubleshooted further for you. This seemed to work for me (and made sense), but I didn't have a good way to test on iOS, so you will have to update the link. For some reason, it was adding padding - 1px - to three sides of the #field form. Try changing #field { padding-left:25px } to #field { padding: 0 0 0 25px; } This should work as long height is set to the same value on both #field and #delete. Let me know if it works, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have tried changing from 24px to 22px but still have alignment issues. Any further suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: That is interesting. I just verified the result (in the jsfiddle on my iPhone. Could you share a link with us to the page you are having trouble with?

Comment: Many thanks for your help @bassplayer7 I have uploaded to [link](http://www.lyyk.com/search.html) which has height set to 24px and also [link](http://www.lyyk.com/search1.html) which has height set to 22px but the 22px doesn't align correctly in FF/Chrome etc and the 24px nor 22px aligns correctly on the iPad/iPhone.

Comment: OK. I troubleshooted further for you. This seemed to work for me (and made sense), but I didn't have a good way to test on iOS, so you will have to update the link. For some reason, it was adding padding - 1px - to three sides of the `#field` form. Try changing `#field { padding-left:25px }` to `#field { padding: 0 0 0 25px; }` This should work as long height is set to the same value on both #field and #delete. Let me know if it works, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to thank you bassplayer7. This solution works perfectly on iOS. Thank you so much!